# XE3 IDE runtime error 217 at 5009763B in Windows 10

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe3

When I try to start delphi XE3 IDE (bds.exe) on my laptop I get "runtime error 217 at 5009763B".
I have recently updated the laptop to Windows 10. This is the first time I tried to run delphi again. So I think it is Windows 10 that is the problem.

I have tried starting with -rfoo, no luck.
The Dutch dealer suggested going to XE8. But not all of my code and not all 3rd party packages are compatible with XE8. So that is no solution either.

The Dutch dealer also told me that some XE3 customers do and some don't have any problems using Windows 10.

Did anybody fix this problem?

Comment: What does `-rfoo` do? What plugins do you have installed? IdeFixPack by any chance?

Comment: -rfoo starts it with a clean new environment.

Comment: I updated IdeFixPack

Comment: I have updated to IdeFixPack 5.93. I have also tried to start de IDE with the entire Embarcadero registry key renamed (both current user and local machine) . I still get the same error. So it looks like it is giving this error even before it uses the registry information.

Comment: Try setting compatibility mode.

Comment: Dalija Prasnikar, thank you. Didn't think of that yet. But it didn't help. Ran it in Windows 8 and Windows 7 mode. As user and as administrator. Same problem. Also ran the troubleshooter. No success.

Comment: Update: I have uninstalled XE3 and reinstalled a new version (update 2). This gives the same runtime error. So still no luck.

Comment: I suggest opening support ticket with [Embarcadero](https://support.embarcadero.com/forms/) directly. Installation and registration issues are handled free of charge. They could have more insight about what is causing you the trouble.

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestion. I contacted (via the Dutch dealer) Embarcadero already. They would rather sell the latest version then help out with this issue. They say "Please be aware that Delphi XE3 is neither certified or supported for use on the Windows 10 platform." I don't expect help from that side. I was hoping on somebody in the communitie that fixed this problem on his/her computer.

Comment: Skip the Dutch dealer - go to the link I provided in previous comment and you will be linked directly with people in support that are dealing with this kind of issues on daily basis. If anyone can give you hints about what to do (try next) it is them. The fact that XE3 is neither supported nor certified to work with Windows 10, does not mean a thing. I am using Delphi 7 and XE4 on Windows 10 without glitch and neither one is certified.

Comment: https://support.embarcadero.com/forms/

Comment: I just opened an issue directly with Embarcadero. Just wait and seee.

Comment: Maybe related, maybe not. I have also installed XE8 on the same W10 machine. It also doesn't run. But with another error message: System error. Code 111. The file name is too long

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the long way out and installed a clean W10 on my laptop. Now I must reinstall everything I use. I installed XE3 and now it runs ok.